# scp a file from one server to another one, got "permission denied"

Tags: centos, ssh, scp

source server IP 162.244.xxx.xxx

```
file -rwxrwxr-x  1 user1 admin    36005278 Sep 10  2013 filename.tar
```

at destination server

```
scp user1@162.244.XXX.XXX:home/filename.tar ./
```

got a Permission denied message. for the source server, I login as user1 and sudo su to get root privilege, I really don't want to change root password since other people may still using it.

for the destination server, It's a virtual server, I didn't open the port so can't push from the source side.

Answer (score 3):

Add in a "/" before "home", unless you are executing this from present working directory of / .

If not, you'll need to provide some more info such as whether the ssh auth works and what permissions are like on source and dest dirs.